# Nested Cron Job in AWS Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

**Requirement:** To send reminder to n users at their appropriate time. E.g user 1 at 9:10AM, user 2 at 10:50PM, user 3 at 4:20 AM and so on.

**Solution in Nodejs**
I have a Nodejs Cron job which runs at every 55 min (i.e. 9:55, 10:55, 11:55). At first it deletes all the child cron job and then fetch data from database and check for reminder settings for users. Based on reminder settings in database, it creates child cron jobs for all users to send the reminders.

**Solution in AWS Lambda**

I created lambda function and schedule it for 55 min. Inside lambda, I am doing the same thing as it was done in nodejs but since lambda's execution is finished, the child cron job are not getting executed.

I thought about step functions but not sure as how to achieve this since it is dynamic. Also someone suggested to trigger SNS but this will also not work in my scenario.

Someone please help me in achieving this with AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have 1 cron job that runs every minute that sends all reminders that need to be sent based on the database information? I don't really see why you need nested cron jobs?

In any case, you could also use DynamoDB's [time to live attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) and a stream that triggers a Lambda function. Create a record to send a reminder at X every Y, with X being the expiration time. The Lambda function triggers, and when done you create a new DDB record with as expiration time X+Y. You might not even need a cron job Lambda in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use aws-sdk to create cloudwatch rules dynamically in your nodejs cron job.

for better contrast, create 2 separate functions.

1. Main Cron Job (delete child cron job in cloud-watch, retrieve data from database, create cloudwatch rules that invoke the child cron job at specific time)
2. Child Cron Job (only send reminders)

To read more: [Nodejs Create CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cloudwatch-examples-sending-events.html)